# Having all meteor packages local

Tags: meteor

I'm been doing a lot of reading on test driven development and continuous integration.  I would like to know if it is possible that I could have all meteor packages installed locally, including all those that display when doing a 'meteor list' at the root of a project?

Comment: It is unclear which packages you want to have, from where are you trying to access them and to which purpose. Pls edit your post and clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can install all your packages locally, but it's a bunch of work, and will cause you problems when trying to update them with new versions.

Package managers were invented for a reason, to help save you from having to install and download everything you are using.

There is no reason that test driven development would push you towards that.

Comment: Having all the dependencies in a git repository is just smart.  Some of the packages are dependent on individual repositories that may not be around after a certain period of time.  If they are all in a git repository then I will have everything to build and/or run the project at a later time.